# How to fix the null value for alert logic?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a logic that if user input, date, and time are not filled it gives the user an alert to have the mentioned sections above, but for some reason, even when I have those sections containing values it still shows null.

The outcome should be:

If there is no value for user input, a due date or time alert should appear.

```js
// variables object

const el = {
  form: document.querySelector(".form"),
  input: document.querySelector(".user-input"),
  list: document.querySelector(".list"),
  date: document.querySelector(".date"),
  time: document.querySelector(".time")
};
//local storage key

const storage_key = "tasks-storage-key";

//Create ID

const createId = () => `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}-${new Date().getTime()}`;

//variable of empty array that gets new task
let taskList = [];

// function that renders task list

//function that creates new tasks with date and time
const creatTask = (task) => {
  const id = createId();

  const taskNew = el.input.value;
  const taskDate = el.date.value;
  const taskTime = el.time.value;



  const tasks = document.createElement("div");

  tasks.innerHTML = `
      
      <div class="task-content">
        <div class="list-of-task">
        <div class="task" data-id="${id}">
        <input type="checkbox" class="tick">
        <div class="new-task-created">${taskNew}</div>
        <label class="due-date">${taskDate}</label>
        <label class="due-time">${taskTime}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="atcion-buttons">
        <button class="edit" data-id="">Edit</button>
        <button class="delete" data-id="">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>`;

  taskList.push(tasks);
  console.log(taskList);
  el.list.appendChild(tasks);
  return task
};

//event listner that listens for add button.
function addTask(taskNew, taskDate, taskTime) {
  if (taskNew == null) {
    alert("Please add a new Task")
  }
  if (taskDate == null) {
    alert("Please add a new Task with a due date");
  }
  if (taskTime == null) {
    alert("Please add a new Task with a due time");
  }
  creatTask();
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <input class="user-input" type="text">
  <input class="date" type="date">
  <input class="time" type="time">
  <button onclick="addTask()" class="add" id="add">+</button>

</div>

<div class="list"></div>
```

Comment: <button onclick="addTask()" class="add" id="add">+</button> you are not passing askNew, taskDate, taskTime into addTask function, within that function you need to find inputs and check their values

Comment: Empty fields will probably have `''` as value and not `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All values obtained from form elements are strings. Even if the element is empty, the value is still `""`, not `null` so checking for `null` isn't the right approach.

Instead test for the absence of any "truthy" value as seen below.

```js
// variables object
const el = {
  form: document.querySelector(".form"),
  input: document.querySelector(".user-input"),
  list: document.querySelector(".list"),
  date: document.querySelector(".date"),
  time: document.querySelector(".time")
};

//local storage key
const storage_key = "tasks-storage-key";

//Create ID
const createId = () => `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}-${new Date().getTime()}`;

//variable of empty array that gets new task
let taskList = [];

// function that renders task list

//function that creates new tasks with date and time
const creatTask = (task) => {
  const id = createId();
  const taskNew = el.input.value;
  const taskDate = el.date.value;
  const taskTime = el.time.value;
  const tasks = document.createElement("div");
  tasks.innerHTML = `     
      <div class="task-content">
        <div class="list-of-task">
        <div class="task" data-id="${id}">
        <input type="checkbox" class="tick">
        <div class="new-task-created">${taskNew}</div>
        <label class="due-date">${taskDate}</label>
        <label class="due-time">${taskTime}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="atcion-buttons">
        <button class="edit" data-id="">Edit</button>
        <button class="delete" data-id="">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>`;

  taskList.push(tasks);
  console.log(taskList);
  el.list.appendChild(tasks);
  return task
};

//event listner that listens for add button.
function addTask(taskNew, taskDate, taskTime) {
  if (!taskNew) {
    alert("Please add a new Task")
  }
  if (!taskDate) {
    alert("Please add a new Task with a due date");
  }
  if (!taskTime) {
    alert("Please add a new Task with a due time");
  }
  creatTask();
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <input class="user-input" type="text">
  <input class="date" type="date">
  <input class="time" type="time">
  <button onclick="addTask()" class="add" id="add">+</button>
</div>
<div class="list"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.

I also found another way of doing it as well after doing further research.

```js
// variables object

const el = {
  form: document.querySelector(".form"),
  input: document.querySelector(".user-input"),
  list: document.querySelector(".list"),
  date: document.querySelector(".date"),
  time: document.querySelector(".time")
};
//local storage key

const storage_key = "tasks-storage-key";

//Create ID

const createId = () => `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}-${new Date().getTime()}`;

//variable of empty array that gets new task
let taskList = [];

// function that renders task list

//function that creates new tasks with date and time
const creatTask = (task) => {
  const id = createId();

  const taskNew = el.input.value;
  const taskDate = el.date.value;
  const taskTime = el.time.value;

  if (taskNew.length == 0) {
    alert("Please add a new Task");
  }
  if (taskDate.length == 0) {
    alert("Please add a new Task with a due date");
  }
  if (taskTime.length == 0) {
    alert("Please add a new Task with a due time");
  }

  const tasks = document.createElement("div");

  tasks.innerHTML = `
      
      <div class="task-content">
        <div class="list-of-task">
        <div class="task" data-id="${id}">
        <input type="checkbox" class="tick">
        <div class="new-task-created">${taskNew}</div>
        <label class="due-date">${taskDate}</label>
        <label class="due-time">${taskTime}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="atcion-buttons">
        <button class="edit" data-id="">Edit</button>
        <button class="delete" data-id="">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>`;

  taskList.push(tasks);
  console.log(taskList);
  el.list.appendChild(tasks);
  return task
};

//event listner that listens for add button.
function addTask() {
  creatTask();
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <input class="user-input" type="text">
  <input class="date" type="date">
  <input class="time" type="time">
  <button onclick="addTask()" class="add" id="add">+</button>

</div>

<div class="list"></div>
```